# cassandra.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

cassandra.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV

env:
apache-cassandra-4.0.0
jdk-11.0.12

ZGC

jvm:
-Xms31G
-Xmx31G

host:
16core 128G

/var/log/message:

```
Jul  4 13:57:10 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd-logind: Removed session 277.
Jul  4 13:57:12 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ cassandra: INFO  [CompactionExecutor:4] 2022-07-04 13:57:12,074 CompactionTask.java:245 - Compacted (24af5250-fb5e-11ec-aa2a-6b96728ba428)
4 sstables to [/data/cassandra/data/data/spaceport/xm_coupon_code_realtime1-d77e7f10ebcc11ecae252faeea3c28c4/nb-6494-big,] to level=0.  27.414MiB to 27.412MiB (~99% of original) i
n 1,812ms.  Read Throughput = 15.127MiB/s, Write Throughput = 15.126MiB/s, Row Throughput = ~123,625/s.  32,718 total partitions merged to 32,689.  Partition merge counts were {1:
32663, 2:23, 3:3, }
Jul  4 13:57:12 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ cassandra: INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2022-07-04 13:57:12,083 SSTable.java:111 - Deleting sstable: /data/cassandra/data/data/spaceport/xm_c
oupon_code_realtime1-d77e7f10ebcc11ecae252faeea3c28c4/nb-6490-big
Jul  4 13:57:12 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ cassandra: INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2022-07-04 13:57:12,084 SSTable.java:111 - Deleting sstable: /data/cassandra/data/data/spaceport/xm_c
oupon_code_realtime1-d77e7f10ebcc11ecae252faeea3c28c4/nb-6493-big
Jul  4 13:57:12 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ cassandra: INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2022-07-04 13:57:12,085 SSTable.java:111 - Deleting sstable: /data/cassandra/data/data/spaceport/xm_c
oupon_code_realtime1-d77e7f10ebcc11ecae252faeea3c28c4/nb-6491-big
Jul  4 13:57:12 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ cassandra: INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2022-07-04 13:57:12,085 SSTable.java:111 - Deleting sstable: /data/cassandra/data/data/spaceport/xm_c
oupon_code_realtime1-d77e7f10ebcc11ecae252faeea3c28c4/nb-6492-big
Jul  4 14:00:01 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: Started Session 293 of user root.
Jul  4 14:01:01 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: Started Session 294 of user root.
Jul  4 14:01:59 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: cassandra.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jul  4 14:02:00 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: Unit cassandra.service entered failed state.
Jul  4 14:02:00 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: cassandra.service failed.
Jul  4 14:02:05 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: cassandra.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul  4 14:02:05 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: Stopped Cassandra Server Service.
Jul  4 14:02:05 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ systemd: Started Cassandra Server Service.
Jul  4 14:02:55 iZ2zec1q29sosy4bdv893qZ cassandra: CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset(Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataI
nputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
```

Comment: So I see some logs, but I’m not sure what the question is.

Comment: Aug  2 15:10:41 iZ2ze8xrqzdpon0ugchh5rZ systemd: cassandra.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV  ; system log :[system.log.2022-08-02.0](http://imgs.itopers.com/system.log.2022-08-02.0)

Comment: Still, there isn't any question. Please don't just throw your logs and errors at us, but also tell us your configuration, what you wanted to do when this error occurred, etc. On the one hand, this might enable us to help you (as what you posted alone just doesn't) and on the other hand it will make us feel less used like robots...

Comment: [cassandra.zip](http://imgs.itopers.com/cassandra.zip) :  java process、debug.log、nodetool status、cassandra.service、cassandra.yaml

Answer (score 2):

The log entries you posted on their own don't explain what the problem is. You will need to review the Cassandra `system.log` for clues.

A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: The problem happened again。Aug  2 15:10:41 iZ2ze8xrqzdpon0ugchh5rZ systemd: cassandra.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV  ; system log :[system.log.2022-08-02.0](http://imgs.itopers.com/system.log.2022-08-02.0)

Comment: @beebol The error messages you are posting are not from your system.log.  Look in the system log for your next clues.

Comment: this error messages is in /var/log/message.

Comment: Do me a favour, please post the question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra and I'd be happy to look into it. Cheers1